# Is there a better way to handle incomplete data in a buffer and reading?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am processing a binary file that is built up of events. Each event can have a variable length. Since my read buffer is a fixed size I handle things as follows:

```
const int bufferSize = 0x500000;
const int readSize = 0x400000;
const int eventLengthMask = 0x7FFE0000;
const int eventLengthShift = 17;
const int headerLengthMask = 0x1F000;
const int headerLengthShift = 12;
const int slotMask = 0xF0;
const int slotShift = 4;
const int channelMask = 0xF;
...
//allocate the buffer we allocate 5 MB even though we read in 4MB chunks
//to deal with unprocessed data from the end of a read
char* allocBuff = new char[bufferSize]; //inFile reads data into here
unsigned int* buff = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(allocBuff); //data is interpretted from here
inFile.open(fileName.c_str(),ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
int startPos = 0;
while(!inFile.eof())
{
    int index = 0;
    inFile.read(&(allocBuff[startPos]), readSize);
    int size = ((readSize + startPos)>>2);
    //loop to process the buffer
    while (index<size)
    {
        unsigned int data = buff[index];
        int eventLength = ((data&eventLengthMask)>>eventLengthShift);
        int headerLength = ((data&headerLengthMask)>>headerLengthShift);
        int slot = ((data&slotMask)>>slotShift);
        int channel = data&channelMask;
        //now check if the full event is in the buffer
        if( (index+eventLength) > size )
        {//the full event is not in the buffer
            break;
        }
        ++index;
        //further processing of the event
    }

    //move the data at the end of the buffer to the beginning and set start position
    //for the next read
    for(int i = index; i<size; ++i)
    {
        buff[i-index] = buff[i];
    }
    startPos = ((size-index)<<2);
}
```

My question is this: Is there a better to handle having unprocessed data at the end of the buffer?

Comment: Numbers. So magic! Wow.

Comment: The magic numbers come from the file format, which will not change as it is burned into the data acquisition hardware. I suppose I could set them up as consts or something though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve it by using a circular buffer rather than a simple array. That, or a circular iterator over the array. Then you don't need to do all that copying — the "start" of the array moves.

Other than that, no, not really.

Comment: I had thought about that but I didn't know how would I get fstream or fread to work with it, any suggestions?

Comment: Iterators, dude. Iterators!

Comment: It has been a long time since I have touched iterators, thanks for reminding me. Will fstream.read(char* s, streamsize n) play nicely with one? (I ask because I would imagine this depends on the function internals)

Comment: "the start of the array moves": at a very large cost in runtime.  From experience, just copying is a lot simpler, and generally a bit faster as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze: What is that large runtime cost? If you're going to talk about cache hits, it's one extra at worse (at the 'seam'). I suppose there is some overhead in tracking the true position of the iterator in the underlying storage, and an extra conditional on each iteration. Meh.

Comment: @JamesMatta: Not really no

Comment: Examples exist on the internet :)

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me that copying data requires X bytes source and X bytes destination, ie. the need to address 2X bytes.  Can't see how that helps cacheing much.

Comment: @MartinJames: Never said it did. I was referring to the utility of having semantically consecutive bytes sitting logically consecutive in memory, so as to increase locality during a forward iteration and minimise cache misses. That is, I was referring to caching during _reads_, not _writes_.

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this problem in the past, I simply copied the
unprocessed data down, and then read from the end of it.  This
is a valid solution (and by far the simplest) if the individual
elements are fairly small and the buffer is large.  (On a modern
machine, "fairly small" can easily be anything up to a couple of
hundred KB.)  Of course, you'll have to keep track of how much
you've copied down, to adjust the pointer and the size of the
next read.

Beyond that:

- You'd be better off using `std::vector<char>` for the buffer.
- You can't convert four bytes read from a disk into an
  `unsigned int` just by casting its address; you have to insert
  each of the bytes into the `unsigned int` where it belongs.
- And finally: you don't check that the read has succeeded
  before processing the data.  Using unbuffered input with an
  `istream` is a bit tricky: your loop should probably be
  something like 
  `while ( inFile.read( addr, len ) || inFile.gcount() != 0 )...`.

Comment: How do I pass the vector<char> to fstream.read(char* s, streamsize n)?

Comment: Also, I think you misinterpretted the casting. I allocate a contigous chunk of memory, 5*2^20 cells of, 1 byte each. The reinterpret cast then lets me use that contiguous memory as 5*2^18 cells of 4 bytes each, that is all I am doing, the byte order is correct on disk so I use fstream.read to get it all byte by byte then I use the casted array to process the data.

Comment: @JamesMatta `inFile.read( v.data(), v.size() )`.  Or if you don't have C++11, `inFile.read( &v[0], v.size() )`.  As for the byte order... You know the byte order on disk, because that is defined by the format.  You don't really know the byte order in memory, as this can (and in fact, in one case, did) change from one version of the compiler to the next; it may change as well if you upgrade machines.

Comment: Of course I know the byte order in memory, the bytes were read into memory exactly as they were on disk otherwise, were I to read in a 4MB file into the char array, I could not go to charArray[0] of the char array and get the first byte of the file so on and so forth. If that is indeed the case then it is impossible to know how to insert the bytes into the appropriate parts of the int. The file byte order is Little-Endian and as there are few examples of non x86 hardware still in common use the memory order will be Little-Endian as well.

Comment: additionally if the memory is, for some reason in Big-Endian order, it is easy enough to use the bswapl assembly command on each element of the int array as it is needed. Your method of bitwise-or (or addition) and shifts is much more complex. My method requires a movl and a bswapl, your method requires (if optimized in assembly to simply put the next byte in the bottom or the register) 4 movb and 3 shll, if unoptimized in assembly it has 4 movb, 3 shll, and 3 orl.

Comment: @JamesMatta Except that there aren't just 2 byte orders.  The difference is that my method works, on all machines, systematically.  Which isn't true for any of the other methods I've seen.

Comment: Could you give an example of something other than big and little endian that is in use? And yes your method works on all machines, but it is, unnecessarily verbose, slow, and can add a noticable overhead. My method works on all x86 machines (which far and away dominate the machines that modern science is done on) and can be made to work in general by inserting a simple #ifdef BIG_E_MEM asm("bswapl %1" : "+r" (intArr[i]) ) #endif and then compiling with that macro defined as needed.

Comment: I just read about the "middle-endian" systems, where the 2-byte order is different than the 4 byte order. First of all, I have to ask how common is that in systems people are likely to be doing data analysis on, I would hazard the guess, almost nonexistant. Big endian systems happen occasionally because of hold-overs from old sun machines. ARM systems might creep in but they are little-endian. So why incurr the cost if a code is going to run on machines that support it. if one is that concerned one can use another #ifdef MIXED_ENDIAN Always correct code #endif

Comment: @JamesMatta I've used systems where the byte order of a long was 3412.  I've also used systems where an `int` wasn't 4 bytes---at least one modern system uses 6 byte `int`.  And who knows what all else.  Endianness isn't the only problem.  As for verbosity: it's wrapped up in one function, which does the correct thing.  As for execution time: I've never found it to be a problem.

Comment: @JamesMatta Re your second response: middle endian systems have come and gone, and at least twice have been among the most widespread (PDP-11, then Microsoft on Intel).  Most of the network still runs on big-endian (and in fact, the usual byte order for Internet protocols is big-endian).  One can be naive, and assume that everything is an Intel, but everyone who has made such a decision in the past (everything is an IBM mainframe, everything is a PDP-11, etc.) have always ended up paying for it.